# Finding out which reference that breaks LaTeX

Tags: biblatex, xetex

When running my .tex file, after having ran `Biber`, it starts to go through numbers and then stops, like so:

```
[44] [45] [46] [47] [48] [49] [50] [51] [52] [53] [54] [55] [56] [57] [58]
[59] [60] [61] [62] [63] [64] [65] [66] [67] [68] [69] [70] [71] [72] [73]
[74]
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
<recently read> }

l.303 \printbibliography[prenote=myprenote]
```

I'm assuming that the numbers indicates references and that there's something wrong with reference number 74 that I need to check out. However, how can I find out which one of my references that is number 74? I've looked through the `aux` file and the `bbl` file, but that hasn't really helped me (I tried going to the 74th reference that was listed in the `aux` file, but I couldn't find anything wrong with it).

Comment: The number are your pages and not the references. Add \errorcontextlines=200. Perhaps you then get enough context to identify the culprit.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, that gave me enough context. Thanks! (I can't understand why this option isn't on by default.)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Perhaps you could write an answer... or should we close the question?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you want to write up an answer here?

Answer (score 3):

The numbers `[69] [70] [71] [72] [73] [74]` are your pages and not the references.

The error itself is somewhere in the bibliography which starts on page 75. Add `\errorcontextlines=200`. Perhaps you then get enough context in the error message to identify the culprit bib-entry.